# Fixing the search indexing on Windows start menu

Tags: windows

This is Windows 11 Pro, but I've had this problem in other Windows versions too.

How do I get it to

1. index everything on my computer (that I might reasonably search for)
2. prioritize commonly accessed files or folders, or at least let me designate them for priority (i.e. make it more useful as a Spotlight-style shortcut tool, not just pure search)

Example of problem #1: I'm reading another SuperUser thread that directs me to the SendTo folder. I search for "SendTo" in the start menu, nothing. I click on "folders" still nothing. I go looking in Explorer and there it is. WTF?

Example of problem #2: I type "Box" and it often defaults to the Box Sync app, which I never want, rather than the Box Sync folder, which I always want. (Changing the folder name is a whole other soap opera with Box, but you see what I mean)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!